# Working with dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I am very new to Python or any language. I want to do something in pure Python for which my data is:

```
2.0 2.0
2.0 4.0
2.0 3.0
2.1 6.0
2.1 4.0
2.1 2.0
2.2 10.0
2.2 2.5
2.2 2.5
```

For each value in the first column (2.0, 2.1, 2.2), I want to take average of the values in second column, and then subtract that average from each each value in second column. For the above data, my output should look like this:

```
2.0 2.0 -1.0
2.0 4.0  1.0
2.0 3.0  0.0
2.1 6.0  2.0
2.1 4.0  0.0
2.1 2.0 -2.0
2.2 10.0 5.0
2.2 2.5  -2.5
2.2 2.5  -2.5
```

How can I do this in Python? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried playing around with python? :)

Comment: You should really give it a try yourself first, and then come back with questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Yes, I can get the average for each value but then don't know how to get the rest of the part.

Comment: "For each value in the first column (2.0, 2.1, 2.2), I want to take average of the values in second column, and then subtract that average from each each value in second column." What? How does the first column affect anything in this case?

Comment: @user3634155 Share the code you have so far! It makes it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You'll want to use a for loop...

Comment: You'll want to use a for loop...

Comment: data = numpy.genfromtxt('a.txt')

Comment: @user3634155: `data = numpy.genfromtxt('a.txt')`?  Your question asks about "pure Python"-- usually that means "without any external libraries"

Comment: data = numpy.genfromtxt('a.txt'), dist = {}, count = {}, for line in data:, key = line[0], if key in dist.keys():, dist[key] += line[1], count[key] += 1, else: dist[key] = line[1], count[key] = 1,   second for loop: for key in dist.keys():, dist[key] /= count[key]

Comment: If you can afford to spring for it, I'd strongly recommend [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Hello-World-Computer-Programming-Beginners/dp/1933988495)

Comment: [Second edition...](http://www.amazon.com/Hello-World-Computer-Programming-Beginners/dp/1617290920/ref=pd_sim_b_2?ie=UTF8&refRID=0DAVVN65SHXRD0S7JGN9)

Answer (score 3):

So I won't give you actual working code, because you didn't provide any, but I'll point you in the right direction

**Step 1:** Read in the file:  You should do this with the `with` construction.  This will automatically handle opening and closing the file and makes your code very readable.

```
f = open("file.txt",'w')
#do stuff
f.close()
```

Is equivalent to

```
with open("file.txt",'w') as f:
    #do stuff
```

This is much cleaner!

**Step 2:** Iterate through your file.  Once you open the file you can start saving contents to memory.  Its best to do this line by line to avoid dumping the whole file into memory (i.e. avoid `file.readlines()`).  You can actual loop directly through your file object with a `for` loop!

```
with open("file.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
         #perform process on each line
```

**Step 3:** Save the data.  For your process, you definitely want a dictionary, so you get points for identifying that.  Your first column will be the keys, and the second and third will make up the value.  The easiest way to store your data is probably with lists(`[value1, value2, value3]`) since they need to change each time you find a line with the same key.  Some pseudo code to do that might be:

```
data = {} 

with open("file.txt",'w') as f:
    for line in f:
        if <first entry of line> in <list of keys in data>:
            #Add second entry of line to tuple 
        else:
            #Create new entry in data with a one entry list of the second entry
```

At the end of this step, you should no longer be inside the `with` structure

**Step 4:** Compute the average.  I would recommend doing a `dict comprehension` for this. These can be sorta tricky, so I'll give you more code for it.  Assuming your dict looks like this at the end of Step 3

```
data = {2.0: [2.0,4.0,3.0],...}
```

Then you can:

```
data = {key, (curVal, <average value>) for key, curVal in data.items()}
```

Only thing you need to do is figure out how to compute the average of values in a list.  I suggest looking into `map()`

**Step 5:** Producing output.  Now you have all your data in a dictionary that looks like this:

```
data = {<some number> : ([<number 1>, <number 2>, <number 3>], <average>), ...}
```

To do this, look into the `format()` function and how to pull data out of nested structures.  If you want to write the data back to a file, you can use `with` again, but change the mode to `'w'`

Hopefully this helps get you on the right track, good luck!